# Save image though webView..?

Tags: android, image, webview

I am able to select text when long pressed but when longClick on image its not showing save as option.? Tried all solutions but not getting results.  I have tried solution on stackoverflow.com but not working for me.
I have tried below stuff

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    // Confirm the view is a webview
    if (v instanceof WebView) {                
        WebView.HitTestResult result = ((WebView) v).getHitTestResult();

        if (result != null) {
            int type = result.getType();

            // Confirm type is an image
            if (type == WebView.HitTestResult.IMAGE_TYPE || type == WebView.HitTestResult.SRC_IMAGE_ANCHOR_TYPE) {
                String imageUrl = result.getExtra();
                Toast.makeText(this, imageUrl, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

are u use registerForContextMenu()?

try this

```
activity.registerForContextMenu(webView);
```